# Django Proper way to handle reverse Foreignkey lookup

Tags: python, django

This took me a couple of hours and I did this for the first time. Because this will happen a lot of times in the future, I was just wondering if this is the proper way to handle reverse lookup in Django.

In models.py I have an Activities class and an ActivitiesThumbnail class. 
In the Activity class I created a static method to get the corresponding activity thumbnail and a method to get all the activities.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Naam", null=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_activities():
        activities_list = Activity.objects.all()
        return activities_list    

    @staticmethod
    def get_activity_thumbnail(activity):
        image = ActivityThumbnail.objects.get(activity__id__exact=activity.id)
        return image


class ActivityThumbnail(Image):
    upload_dir = 'static/uploads/images/thumbnails/activities'
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, blank=True, null=True)
```

In views.py I first create a list with all the activities. 
Next I create a list called activities_list_with_images and use a for-loop to populate that list with lists containing the activity object and the corresponding image object.

```
def activities(request):
    activities_list = Activity.get_all_activities()
    activities_list_with_images = []
    for activity in activities_list:
        activities_list_with_images.append([activity, Activity.get_activity_thumbnail(activity)])

    context = {'city_id': city_id,
               'activities_list': activities_list,
               'activities_list_with_images': activities_list_with_images}
    return render(request, 'hotel/activities.html', context)
```

In activities.html I call the activities_list_with_images list and use a foreach loop to show them all to the screen.

```
{% for activity in activities_list_with_images %}
    <div>
        <p>{{ activity.0.short_description }}</p>
        <img src="/{{ activity.1.image }}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This way works just fine, but I would like to know if this is a correct approach.

Comment: Why is `get_activity_thumbnail` a staticmethod? That makes no sense: it takes an activity and does some action on it. It should be a normal method. Although even then, it is pointless; it can be replaced by `activity.activitythumbnail_set.all()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @DanielRoseman. I have removed the staticmethod, but this is resulting in an error (even after adding `self`) The reason I do not use `activity.activitythumbnail_set.all()` is because I need to get them directly corresponding to the activity. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Well, yes: `self` *is* the activity in that method.

Answer (score 0):

As you expected, there's a much easier way to get reverse lookups working.

As soon as you create a ForeignKey between two Models, you can access both of them from the other one:

1. From Activity to ActivityThumbnail: `activity.activitythumbnail_set.all()`
2. From ActivityThumbnail to Activity: `activitythumbnail.activity`

Does that make sense?

Comment: Should I use this in the `for activity in activities_list` loop?

Comment: No, you need to change a couple of more things. First, return all the ActivityThumbnail from your view to your template. Then loop over them and use `{{ activitythumbnail.activity }}`

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks @EmilSterstrom